# r - foreach package returns error message

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm unable to run any of the examples in the foreach package, instead I get the following error message

```
Error in UseMethod("conditionMessage") : 
  no applicable method for 'conditionMessage' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I have tried to reinstall the foreach package but to no avail.

Session Info

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] doSNOW_1.0.16     snow_0.4-2        doParallel_1.0.11 iterators_1.0.9   foreach_1.4.4     sp_1.2-7          RSQLite_2.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15       magrittr_1.5       bit_1.1-12         xtable_1.8-2       lattice_0.20-35    R6_2.2.2           rlang_0.2.0        blob_1.1.0         tools_3.4.4        grid_3.4.4         DBI_0.8           
[12] htmltools_0.3.6    crosstalk_1.0.0    yaml_2.1.17        bit64_0.9-7        leaflet_1.1.0.9000 digest_0.6.15      tibble_1.4.2       shiny_1.0.5        codetools_0.2-15   htmlwidgets_1.0    memoise_1.1.0     
[23] mime_0.5           compiler_3.4.4     pillar_1.2.1       httpuv_1.3.6.2
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide the code that got you the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading to R-3.4.4